# Evaluating the series mentioned below

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)$
$+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5}\right)$
$+\cdots\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n}+\cdots \frac{n-1}{n}\right)$

---

For each block there represents a series.How to find the Tn term for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k) = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}.$

**masked hint**: 
after using the above identify to compute $T_n$, you can use the above identity a second time to compute $T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_n$.

Comment: okay! thanks T_n = (n-1)/2

Comment: @Danjing_Chaw answer edited.